# Ambiguous extension method call between float and double

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I have following extension methods, one for float and one for double.

```
public static string ToTimeString(this float f, TimeStringAccuracy accuracyFlags = DefaultAccuracyFlags, TimeStringSeparator separator = DefaultSeparator)


public static string ToTimeString(this double d, TimeStringAccuracy accuracyFlags = DefaultAccuracyFlags, TimeStringSeparator separator = DefaultSeparator)
```

When i call the functions from Visual Studio unit tests the tests run correctly and the call is not ambiguous. When i call the functions from Unity3D code for float (using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)) the call is ambiguous between these two. Why doesn't the compiler know that it should be calling the float extension? Might it be Mono causing this?

This is the call:

```
float i = 1f;
i.ToTimeString();
```

Compiler error:

```
Assets/Scipts/UIScripts/GameplayUIWindow.cs(61,48): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: ToTimeString(this double, TimeStringAccuracy, TimeStringSeparator)' and `ToTimeString(this float, TimeStringAccuracy, TimeStringSeparator)'
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with Mono, can't replicate the issue with Visual studio/windows.

Comment: Different compilers, different errors ... but the method definition is indeed somewhat ambiguous. It's better to provide only one, and where you need the other data type just cast it in the code that's using it.

Comment: I second Cocos' idea, it makes more sense.

Comment: @Habib Might be due to the fact that unity uses a older version of mono

Comment: I think I'll just remove the float extension and do the cast to double in the code using the extension. Currently the casting is done in the extension method anyway. Damn I wish they would update the Mono finally :(  I disagree with LearnCocos2D, I think it's better idea to have extension for each numeric type to achieve cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version instead:

```
public static string ToTimeString<T>(this T target, TimeStringAccuracy accuracyFlags = DefaultAccuracyFlags, TimeStringSeparator separator = DefaultSeparator) where T : struct
```

It may compile to different code in Mono but still allow you to use the code in the way you want. As a disclaimer, I recommend doing some type checking on the type parameter T inside of the method body to guarantee that the method behaves the way you expect for expected types (such as float and double) and throws exceptions for unexpected types (such as int or Enum).